# How to cap velocity in Unity 3D using AddForce with ForceMode.VelocityChange

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics, physics

I am working on a player controller and having trouble with limiting the character's velocity. The character seems to accelerate indefinitely.

I am updating the character's velocity using `rb.AddForce(movement * movementSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange)`, where `movement` is a normalized `Vector3` (with values only for `x` and `z`) and `movementSpeed` is a public float giving the desired movement speed. I realize that it would be trivial to cap the character's velocity by setting it directly but I'm under the impression that setting `rb.velocity` directly is bad practice (which I'm not entirely sure is true).

My fixed update function:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    movement.Normalize();
    rb.AddForce(movement * movementForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

I have tried adding a conditional statement checking if the velocity is greater than the desired maximum and, if true, adding a force in the opposing direction. This results in stuttering. The character's velocity is reset to 0 and forced to accelerate again.

```
    Vector3 currMovement = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);
    float currMagnitude = currMovement.magnitude;
    if (currMagnitude > movementSpeed) {
        rb.AddForce(currMovement * (-1 * movementSpeed / currMagnitude), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

#### TL;DR

- How to cap velocity when using `rb.AddForce(movement, ForceMode.VelocityChange)`?
- Do I even need to use `rb.AddForce` or can I directly set `rb.velocity`?

Comment: Setting `rb.velocity` directly is not bad practice if you already can calculate what the rigidbody velocity ought to be at the current frame, and the presence or absence of other colliders, gravity, or other physics considerations are meant to be irrelevant in that calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with setting the velocity directly, especially when it comes to capping velocity. I think people tend to visualize velocity better when they're adding a force in a direction rather than directly setting it, but no, in short, I don't think it's bad practice.

Have a look at Unity's [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) documentation. I'd do something like:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    movement.Normalize();
    rb.AddForce(movement * movementForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.x, -SomeMaximumVelocity, SomeMaximumVelocity), 
                              rb.velocity.y, 
                              Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.z, -SomeMaximumVelocity, SomeMaximumVelocity));
}
```

Comment: Mind that when clamping components separately, it will generally result in a "box"-like clamping rather than a circular clamping one might prefer.

Comment: [Here's](https://forum.unity.com/threads/addforce-vs-addrelativeforce-vs-rigidbody-velocity.32808/) a good answer when to use AddForce and when to set velocity directly. And [here's](https://forum.unity.com/threads/limit-the-velocity-of-an-object-after-addforce.531229/) an answer on how to clamp the velocity